# how to display trailing zeros in input type number (angular, js)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have to display in UI on input tag, even whole numbers like 15 as `15.00` (or as many decimals user decides upon).
I'm currently using an input of type number with attributes min and max.

So far, the only options which I have seen online are to use input type `text`. (trying not to as it doesn't make sense to switch to text, as I'm only working with numbers).

I have tried using step attribute but doesn't cover the case for trailing zeros (neither chrome or firefox will show trailing zeros for a number).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

If decimals set as 4, the following needs to happen:
ex.
15.2   shown as 15.2000
100    shown as 100.0000

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That helps others to figure out your situation little better.

Comment: `(trying not to as it doesn't make sense to switch to text, as I'm only working with numbers)` I will be cruel and say, try, 00001 = 1, but "00001" != 1.... Hint hint (if its only for UI ofc)

Comment: You might want to consider using an "input mask".

Comment: @Adriano first time i hear about input mask, do you know of any good tutorials where i can learn more about this?

Comment: Well, this is a good place to start: https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below of using `ng-blur` with `parseFloat` and `toFixed`

**Option 1:**

Use ng-blur option to format entered number by parseFloat with toFixed(4)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.format = function(event, $filter) {
    const val = event.target.value;
    const decimalCnt = val.split('.')[1] ? val.split('.')[1].length : 0;
    event.target.value = decimalCnt && decimalCnt > 4 ? event.target.value : parseFloat(val).toFixed(4)
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="test" ng-blur="format($event)"><br>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xxxGoNK

**Option 2:**
Create attribute directive for displaying entered value with decimal values

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $filter) {});

app.directive("decimalValues", function($filter) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
      element.on('blur', function(e) {
        let val = element.val();
        const decimalCnt = val.split('.')[1] ? val.split('.')[1].length : 0;
        val = decimalCnt && decimalCnt > 4 ? val : parseFloat(val).toFixed(4)
        element.val(val)
      })
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <input type="text" ng-model="test" decimal-values><br>

    <br>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NWWqZQY

Comment: will this change the actual value. ex   10.123456   will be changed to 10.1234  ?   i'm trying not to loose the rest of the decimal value

Comment: @ArbolDie the toFixed is the decimal point you can range to.. You should read the answer first, but now im off to test what an infinite toFixed will do for Pie in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a custom directive:

```
app.directive("toFix", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: postLink
  }

  function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
    ngModel.$render = function() {
      elem.val(parseFloat(ngModel.$viewValue).toFixed(attrs.toFix));
    }
    ngModel.$parsers=[(_ => parseFloat(_))];
    ngModel.$formatters=[(_ => parseFloat(_).toFixed(attrs.toFix))];
  }
})
```

Usage:

```
<input type="number" to-fix="4" ng-model="num1">
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/lee4DlIwzylDx6DDJSeV?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to do that with HTML only. But you can use JavaScript's `Number.prototype.toFixed`. For example:

```
15.2.toFixed(4) // 15.2000
100..toFixed(4) // 100.0000
```

Comment: yea, i have seen this but unfortunately not an option as toFixed will cut off any extra decimals in the value, which can then affect other results